# html and CSS image layering and opacities

Tags: html, css

I have an html page with a gradient background. Then I have an image in front of this. I would like this image to have an opacity of 0.2. Then I have a form. The fieldset opacity is set to .95. However, when I run the script, the whole page (except the header) has an opacity of .2 How do I get it where just the image is 0.2 and the form remains 0.95 I tried various positioning and i can't seem to get it. My css and html code is attached as well as a screen shot of the image when at .2-.3. The 2 commands at the bottom of the CSS are the ones im using in my  Your help is most appreciated. Thank you

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <script src="Scripts/Global.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Styles/Design.css">
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="body"><br></div>
      <div id="header">
         <h1>Waste Entry Form</h1>
         <p id="Date"></p>
         <div id="headerIcon"><img src="Images/Logos/Logo5.jpg" style="width:90px;height:40px"></div>
      </div>
      <div id="content"> </div>
      <div id="wrapper">
         <center>
            <div>
               <form action="DataEntry.asp" method="post" class="formstyle">
                  <fieldset>
                     <table border="0px">
                        <tr>
                           <td colspan = "2"  id="formHeader">
                              Select Shift
                           </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                           <td  class="spaceUnder" id="formBody">Day Shift&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                              <input type="radio" name="Shift" id="dayShift" value="Day Shift">
                           </td>
                           <td  align="center" class="spaceUnder" id="formBody">Evening Shift &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                              <input type="radio" name="Shift" id="eveningShift" value="Evening Shift">
                           </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                           <td colspan = "2" id="formHeader">
                              Select Date and Time
                           </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                           <td class="spaceUnder"  id="formBody">Date: &nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="date" id="theDate"></td>
                           <td  align="center" class="spaceUnder"  id="formBody">Time: &nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="time" value="22:15:00"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                           <td colspan = "2"  id="formHeader">
                              Enter Equipment & Waste 
                           </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                           <td class="spaceUnder"  id="formBody">
                              Type:&nbsp;&nbsp;
                              <select id="formSelect">
                                 <option value="">Choose Equipment</option>
                                 <option value="Raw Material">Raw Material</option>
                                 <option value="Spiral Freezer">Spiral Freezer</option>
                                 <option value="Palletizer">Palletizer</option>
                                 <option value="Bagger">Bagger</option>
                                 <option value="Fryer">Fryer</option>
                              </select>
                           </td>
                           <td class="spaceUnder"  id="formBody">Scrap Waste lbs: 
                              <input type="number" name="quantity" min="1" max="50">
                           </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                           <td align ="right" colspan = "2"> <input class="SaveIcon" title="Save" type="button1"  onclick="SaveDataEntry()" style="background-image: url(Images/Save.png); cursor:pointer"></input></td>
                        </tr>
                        <br>
               </form>
               </table>
               </fieldset>
            </div>
      </div>
      </center>

      <div id="footer">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
         <input title="Main Page" type="button" onclick="MainPage()" style="background-image: url(Images/Home1.bmp)"></input>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
         <a href="#" onclick="history.go(-1)">  <input title="Previous Page" type="button" onclick="PreviousPage()" style="background-image: url(Images/BackNav1.bmp)"></input>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a>
         <input title="Data Entry Page" type="button" onclick="DataEntr()" style="background-image: url(Images/Edit1.bmp)"></input>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
         <a href="HeatMap.html"><input title="Heat Map" type="button" onclick="HeatMap()" style="background-image: url(Images/Fahrenheit1.bmp)"></input>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a>
         <a href="SafetyScreen.html"> <input title="Safety Screen" type="button" onclick="Safety()" style="background-image: url(Images/Safety.bmp)"></input>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a>   
         <input title="Standard Thresholds" type="button" onclick="StandardThresholds()" style="background-image: url(Images/StandardThreshold.png)"></input>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
         <input title="Trending" type="button" onclick="Trending()" style="background-image: url(Images/Trend.bmp)"></input>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
         <input title="Alarm and Events" type="button" onclick="Alarm()" style="background-image: url(Images/Alarm.bmp)"></input>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
         <input title="Report Expert" type="button" onclick="ReportExpert()" style="background-image: url(Images/ReportExpert.png)"></input>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
         <input title="Data Entry Reports" type="button" onclick="DataEntrSSRS()" style="background-image: url(Images/DataEntry.bmp)"></input>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;     
      </div>
      <script>
         var d = new Date();
         document.getElementById("Date").innerHTML = d.toUTCString();                   
      </script>
      <script>
         var d = new Date();
         document.getElementById("Date2").innerHTML = d.toUTCString();                  
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

CSS Code:

```
html {
    min-height: 100%;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    background: #70bg32;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient( to left bottom, #0096DD, white);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient( to left bottom, #0096DD, white);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient( to left bottom, #0096DD, white);
    background: -o-linear-gradient( to left bottom, #0096DD, white);
    background: linear-gradient( to left bottom, #0096DD, white);



}
h1 {
    position:relative;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    bottom:30px;
    font-size: 35pt;

}
h2 {
    color: black;
    text-align: center;

}
legend {
    font-size:  1.4em;
    font-weight:  bold;
    position:  relative;
    color: black;
    border:2px;
}

male{
    width: 10.5em;
    height: 10.5em;
}
input[type=radio] {
    -webkit-transform: scale(4, 4);

}
input[type=button] {
    width:35px; 
    height: 35px; 
    background-color: transparent; 
    background-position:center; 
    background-repeat:no-repeat; 
    border:0px;
    position: relative;
    top: 7px;
}
input[type=button1] {
    width:35px; 
    height: 35px; 
    background-color: transparent; 
    background-position:center; 
    background-repeat:no-repeat; 
    border:0px;position: relative;
    top: 0px;
}
input[type=date] {
    height:40px;
    width:250px;
    font-size:18pt;
}
input[type=number] {
    height:40px;
    width:60px;
    font-size:18pt;
}
input[type=time] {
    height:40px;
    width:250px;
    font-size:18pt;
}
table{
    position:relative;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    top:0;
    border-spacing:0px; 
    border-collapse: separate;
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;

}
textarea { 
    resize: none; 
}
#formSelect{
    height:40px;
    width:250px;
    font-size:16pt;

}
#header {
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
    height:60px;
    background:#000000;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
#formHeader {
    position:relative;
    height:35px;
    background:#000000;
    top:-18px;
    left:0;
    color: white;

    text-align: center;
    font-size:20pt;
    font-weight: bold;

}
#formBody{
    position:relative;
    height:35px;
    top:0px;
    left:0;
    color: black;   
    text-align: center;
    font-size:20pt;
    font-weight: bold;


}
#formTextArea{

    position:relative;
    height:35px;
    top:0px;
    left:0;
    color: black;   
    text-align: center;
    font-size:20pt;
    font-weight: bold;
}
#content {
    padding:10px;
    padding-bottom:80px;   /* Height of the footer element */
}
#footer {
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    background:#000000;
}

#Date{
    position:relative;
    color: white;
    text-align: left;
    top: -80px;
    left:5px;
}
#headerIcon{
    position:relative;
    color: white;
    text-align: right;
    top: -140px;
    right:5px;
}
#forms{
    display:inline-block;
    max-width:100%;
}
p#formTitles {
    color: white;
    position:relative;

    text-align: center;
    font-size:10pt;
    font-weight: bold;
}
#waterMark{
    opacity: 0.1;
    min-height: 100%;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    min-height: 100%;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    background-image: url("../Images/Logos/download42.jpg");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
.TriLogo1{
    width:90px;
    height:120px;
    position: fixed;
    top:120px;
    left:150px;
}
.spaceUnder{
    padding-bottom: 2em;
    padding-top: 2em;

}
.spaceAbove{
    padding-top: 0em;
}
.spaceUnderTitle{
    padding-bottom: 1em;
}
#wrapper {
    background:transparent url("../Images/Logos/download42.jpg") no-repeat center center;
        min-height: 100%;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    min-height: 100%;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    position:relative;
    top:120px;
    opacity:0.9;  /* I need this to not effect the form as well. i want this low like .2 */
    background-repeat:no-repeat;

}

fieldset{
    border:1;
        min-height: 100%;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    background: #70bg32;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient( to left bottom, #2A59A1, white);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient( to left bottom, #2A59A1, white);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient( to left bottom, #2A59A1, white);
    background: -o-linear-gradient( to left bottom, #2A59A1, white);
    background: linear-gradient( to left bottom, #2A59A1, white);
    display:inline; 
    width:60%;
    padding:0px;
    border-spacing:0px; 
    border-collapse: separate;
    opacity:0.95;
    position:relative;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The opacity property affects not only itself but addtionally all its children. So you have to change the html markup or use pseudo elements:

```
div#wrapper:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: transparent url("...") no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover;
  opacity: 0.2;
}
```

[Demo](http://codepen.io/codelabr/full/GgEpYv/)

Hope that's what you're looking for!